# prime factors of a number

Tags: c, primes

I was trying to develop a code to compute the [prime factors][1] of a number, but I am getting nothing as output. Can anyone point out where I am making the mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>


int prime_check(int i)
{
    int j;
    for(j=2;j<i;j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
            return 0;
    }
    return i;
}
void prime(int n)
{
    double c=sqrt(n);
    int i;
    int p[10];
    //printf("factors are: ");
    for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
    {
        p[i]=prime_check(i);
        //printf("%d  ",p[i]);

        if(n % p[i] == 0)
            printf("%d ",p[i]);

    }
}

main()
{


    //printf("enter the number:\t");
    int num=36;
    //scanf("%d",&num);
    prime(num);
}
```

TO EVERYONE I GOT THE ANSWER! Thanks Jeff Mercado for showing me my mistake

Comment: Your `printf` statements are guarded by conditon constructs, If there is no output means one of those conditions does not result in `true`, Can you not debug it?

Comment: no THAT PRINTS ALL PRIME NUMBERS..not the prime factors

Comment: What?  First you get nothing as output but now it's printing all the numbers?  So what is it?

Comment: I can get all the prime numbers which are less than sqrt(number)…but that not I want to get ! I want to get prime factors..which i am not getting in any cases!!!!!!

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: **-1** If you put proper information in the Q instead of `but I am getting nothing as output.` You wouldn't have to scream the big bold text and btw that is very offensive, considering you don't pay people here to help you. You deserve a -1.

Comment: Henning Makholm-I looked in the debugger..unfortunately everything was showing there as I wanted….but nothing is still printing nothing

Comment: @ALS-my caps lock button is not working fine…I did not write anything to offense u…if i wrote..then i am sorry

Comment: Removing the Downvote, but add proper information in the Q, What are you trying? What problem you are facing? What is the output you get? and what is the intended output? Makeup a perfect Q and it saves everyone a lot of time and effort.

Comment: LOL, you're blaming it on your caps lock key? Remarkable understanding of English, that key has, then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    void prime(int n)
    {
           int c= floor(sqrt(n));         //updated code 
           int i;
           int p[10];
           //printf("factors are: ");
           for(i=1;i<=c;i++)
           {
                p[i]=prime_check(i);
                if(p[i] == 0)                //added check
                      continue;
                //printf("%d  ",p[i]);

                if(n % p[i] == 0)
                printf("%d ",p[i]);

          }
     }
```